# the space of <a> tag does not fit into its content like <img> tag

Tags: html, css

Here is code

```
<a href="#" style="background-color:red; padding:30px;">
<img src="cat.jpg" style="width:150px; vertical-align:bottom;"/></a>
```

This code would result in the following picture

[image]
I am just wondering why the anchor tag does not grow its size to fit into the image. As you can see, the image overflows. I understand that if i have "display:inline-block", I will get this problem solved, but I want to know why this happens because when you have text inside anchor tag, the area will grow based on its content as the following picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `<a>` tag to  `{ display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

The space at bottom of a is line-height of img

```
a img {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Or you also can set img display: block if a display block too

Comment: Yeah I understand how to fit it but I just want to know why the anchor tag does not grow its size based on its content. you know the picture overflows